# Class set to VB6 globalmultiuse not being created automatically?

Tags: function, dll, vb6, global

I need to construct a VB6 DLL that has global functions available to a VB6 application. Within the DLL, I have placed the functions inside a class and made the class instancing to `6. GlobalMultiUse`. I have referenced the DLL from the project.

VB6 is supposed to create a hidden instance of the class on first call to a function within the class so that the class name does not need to be in front of the call i.e. not `class.function()` but just `function()`. However, when the call is made the error 453 occurs '*Can't find DLL entry point function() in DLL*'.

If I do put the class name in front of the function it works.

Any VB6 programmers still out there who knows why the hidden instance of the class is not being created?

Comment: Did you make the class methods `Public`?

Comment: Did you correctly set a reference to the VB6 DLL?  Are you sure that it does not use any other third-party non-COM DLLs or APIs?

Comment: Maybe you have a routine in your non-DLL project with the same name as the DLL routine you are trying to call?